# Apply style to a DataFrame using index/column from a list of tuples in Python/Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of tuples that represent DataFrame index row number and a column name, in a form:

```
[(12, 'col3'), (16, 'col7'), ...].
```

I need to be able to find rows/column values that correspond to those tuple values in another dataframe and mark them red for example. Usually I use

```
df.style.apply(...)
```

from here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html and it works but in this case I am not sure how to map those tuple values with a dataframe in a function. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: All values always matched?

Comment: Only values located in a dataframe on the 12th row and in a column col3 and so on should be colored red for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom function with [`at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) for set values by `tups`:

```
tups = [(12, 'col3'), (16, 'col7'), ...]

def highlight(x):
    r = 'background-color: red'
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    #rewrite values by selecting by tuples
    for i, c in tups:
        df1.at[i, c] = r
    return df1

df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

Comment: Brilliant, it works but instead of 'red' you need to add something like 'background-color: red', otherwise no coloring will show. Thanks!